# iOS - Allow user to download file from documents directory but not to upload file using iTunes

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, file-sharing

Here is a situation I have a data file in document directory which is being updated in the application every now and then. So I want to save it to my desktop using iTunes. But I don't want that the file should be uploaded back to my application. i.e. I want that user can download the file but can not upload any.

I was thinking to have the data file on some other location like Library and put a button on application settings saying "Prepare backup" that will copy that data file in Document directory, from where user can download it. If user uploads any thing it won't make any difference as my current file is in Library directory.

This is just a thought,
can anyone suggest me other way or the above way is good to go?

**Edit**: I just need that after the successful export user can view the data file (may be later) without support of the application.

Comment: I don't understand your question or end-goal.  Specifically, what do you mean by "I want that user can download the file but can not upload any?"

Comment: How does the user restore from the backup?

Comment: @SteveRogers This is not exactly a backup but rather a copy of the file that can be viewed (later) without support of the application.

Comment: Ah, ok.  So maybe think of it as an "export" file?  Then your approach is best.  Keep your internal data somewhere private and offer an "export" selection into iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.
But what you can do is check (using an timer every 10 seconds) if a new file is added to the documents directory and then delete it programmatically.
But this ofcourse doesn't disable the replacement of files.

Comment: An Alternative to File System Events in Apple documentation. There is an example for iOS in [AVPlayerDemo](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVPlayerDemo/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010101) (look DirectoryWatcher class).

Comment: the link I provided watches the directory for a change in that. and notifies on change. just a better/efficient alternative to 10 seconds timer.